# Regex to tokenize log line

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I've a log line as follows:

> [2021-03-10 00:13:32.901] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3] [DEBUG] [4231c006d9083a302fce59d5f0957226] [42c5ac3c0acfc68d] [GreeterImpl] Hello John

It's 6 blocks of text within `[]` and then the rest. I'm looking for a regex to extract the text within `[]`, and also at the end. A text block within `[]` can be empty.

I tried `(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\])+([^\[\]]+)` but it only matches the first block in `[]`. I've also tried `(?:(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\]))+([^\[\]]+)` but that doesn't match anything.

FWIW, the regex will be implemented in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short edit:** This slightly simpler regular expression works too:

```
(?:(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*)|(?:(?<=\])[^\[\]]*$)
```

I have taken it from your own comment.

Original answer follows.

**TL;DR**

```
(?:(?<=^\[| \[)[^\[\]]*)|(?:(?<=\] )[^\[\]]*$)
```

**Explanation:** There are two parts separated by `|`, “or”.

1. The first part, `(?:(?<=^\[| \[)[^\[\]]*)` matches what is inside square brackets. `[^\[\]]*` near the end matches the longest possible run of characters that are neither `[` nor `]`. `(?<=^\[| \[)` requires it to be preceded either by the beginning of the string and a `[` or by  `[`. Finally I have put the whole thing into a non-capturing group to make sure that the lookbehind has precedence over the `|`.
2. The second part, `(?:(?<=\] )[^\[\]]*$)`, matches what is outside square brackets at the end of the log line (`Hello John` in the example). This time the run of non-brackets must be preceded by `]`  and followed by the end of the line.

**See it in action:**

1. [On regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ztdCNp/1/) where I built it
2. In Java:

   ```
   String logLine = "[2021-03-10 00:13:32.901]"
           + " [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3] [DEBUG]"
           + " [4231c006d9083a302fce59d5f0957226] [42c5ac3c0acfc68d]"
           + " [GreeterImpl] Hello John";

   Matcher m = Pattern
           .compile("(?:(?<=^\\[| \\[)[^\\[\\]]*)|(?:(?<=\\] )[^\\[\\]]*$)")
           .matcher(logLine);
   while (m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group());
   }
   ```

Output is:

> ```
> 2021-03-10 00:13:32.901
> DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3
> DEBUG
> 4231c006d9083a302fce59d5f0957226
> 42c5ac3c0acfc68d
> GreeterImpl
> Hello John
> ```

**A different idea: String.split()**

```
    String[] tokens = logLine.split("\\] \\[|\\] (?!\\[)");
    assert tokens[0].startsWith("[") : logLine;
    tokens[0] = tokens[0].substring(1);

    for (String token : tokens) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

Output is the same as before.

I am splitting at either `] [` or `]`  *not* followed by `[` (for the last split). It leaves the first `[` intact, so I have to remove that separately, which is not so nice. Otherwise I find it simpler to understand than the other solutions.

Comment: That's some serious regex foo you've got here :) Seems like `(?:(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*)|(?:(?<=\])[^\[\]]*$)` is slightly simpler and works too.

Comment: My workaround until I asked here was to simply look for the indices of `[` and `]`, and extract the substring in between. When index of `[` is `-1`, we can take the rest of the string. Although slightly more code (3 lines?), IMO it's simpler than splitting and removing first char. The regex solutions put forth thus far are elegant and good learning.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make use of the `\G` anchor to match the `[...]` parts at the start, and optionally the rest in group 2.

That way you can differentiate which parts are between the square brackets and which part is the rest.

```
\G\[([^][]*)]\h+([^][]+$)?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string for the first match
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^][]*` Match 0+ occurrences or any char except `[` or `]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `]\h+` Match the closing `]` and 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^][]+$` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `[` or `]`
- `)?` Close group 2 and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcCmyH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9WcRvV)

In Java with the doubled backslashes

```
String regex = "\\G\\[([^\\]\\[]*)]\\h+([^\\]\\[]+$)?";
```

Comment: This is close to what I tried initially, except for the `\G` anchor, that I wasn't aware of. However, I like Ole V.V. answer little better because he uses the OR operator, making the intent clearer that the two groups can't actually coexist. I've upvoted you for taking the time, and introducing me to the `\G` anchor. That said, I think both the answers can be combined also, but I'm not going to make that effort.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Thank you, that is perfectly ok :-) Btw, you could shorten the pattern of  Ole V.V. by removing the non capture groups like `(?<=\[)[^\[\]]*|(?<=\])[^\[\]]*$` As a small note, using only the alternation could possibly also match this example https://regex101.com/r/pVAJS8/1 where using the `\G` anchor the string has to start with the opening/closing square bracket format. See https://regex101.com/r/GoKYpA/1

Comment: Given that the format is well defined (it's a log line, not user provided), I don't think we need to worry about a mismatched input like `]test [test`, but good to know, of course.